# Bind recursion and delegation allow-query-on denied

Tags: bind

For educational purposes it is asked to us and required:
To sum up ...

- Using BIND DNS

**First Step:**

- **In first server** using same daemon
- Create a TLD zone (as parent) on an specific IP address
- Create a child zone on another IP address
- Delegate child zone at the parent one
- Allow recursion from parent to child

Then...

**Second Step:**

- **In second server** using an identical configuration
- Setup master/slave relationship between 1st and 2nd server parent zone
- Setup master/slave relationship between 1st and 2nd server child zone zone

Then...

**Third Step:**

- Inverse master slave relationship between 1st and 2nd server for
  child zone zone
- Setup DNSSEC
- Setup Dynamic DNS Using dhcpd

I stop here as I'm blocked at the first step.

Here is my TLD named `lab.` zone file

```
    $ORIGIN lab.

    ; Time a cache will keep responses
    $TTL 1h

    ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;;  ZONE : lab.
    ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;; ---------------------------------------
    ;; START OF AUTHORITY
    ;; ---------------------------------------

    @   IN  SOA ns0 hostmaster (
                        ; serial
                        2020040400
                        ; Frequency of zone transfer from slave
                        12h
                        ; delay before slave retries after a zone transfer failure
                        15m
                        ; Time a slave will keep the data in case it cannot contact the master
                        1w
                        ; Time a cache will keep negative responses (NXDOMAIN)
                        1h
                    )
    ;; --------------------------------------
    ;; NAME SERVER
    ;; --------------------------------------

    @       IN  NS  ns0
    ns0     IN  A   10.31.0.220

    ;; v0.1 seems bad ??
    ;; --------------------------------------
    ;; SUB DOMAIN / DELEGATION
    ;; --------------------------------------

    ;;demo      IN  NS  ns1.demo
    ;;ns1.demo  IN  A   10.31.0.221

    ;; v0.2 not better
    ;; --------------------------------------
    ;; SUB DOMAIN / DELEGATION
    ;; --------------------------------------
    ;;demo      IN  A   10.31.0.221

   ;;$ORIGIN demo.lab.
   ;;$TTL 1h;
   ;;@      IN  NS  ns1
   ;;@      IN  NS  ns0.lab. 
   ;;ns1        IN  A   10.31.0.221
```

Here is my child domain named `demo.lab.` zone file

```
$ORIGIN demo.lab.

; Time a cache will keep responses
$TTL 1h

;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;;  ZONE : demo.lab.
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;; ---------------------------------------
;; START OF AUTHORITY
;; ---------------------------------------

@   IN  SOA ns1 hostmaster (
                    ; serial
                    2020040400
                    ; Frequency of zone transfer from slave
                    12h
                    ; delay before slave retries after a zone transfer failure
                    15m
                    ; Time a slave will keep the data in case it cannot contact the master
                    1w
                    ; Time a cache will keep negative responses (NXDOMAIN)
                    1h
                )
;; --------------------------------------
;; NAME SERVER
;; --------------------------------------

@   IN  NS  ns1
ns1 IN  A   10.31.0.221

@   IN  NS  ns0.lab.
```

Here is my `named.conf` file

```
options {
    directory "/etc/bind";

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035

    listen-on { 
        10.31.0.220;
        10.31.0.221; 
    };      

    recursion yes;

    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-recursion-on { any;  };
    allow-query-cache { any; };

    minimal-responses no;
    querylog yes;

};

zone "lab." IN {
    type master;
    file "zone/2/db-lab";
    allow-query {
        10.31.0/24;
        10.31.10/24;
        10.31.0.221;
    };

    allow-query-on {
        10.31.0.220;
    };

};

zone "demo.lab." IN {
    type master;
    file "zone/2/db-demo.lab";
    allow-query {
        10.31.0/24;
        10.31.10/24;
        10.31.0.220;
    };

    allow-query-on {
        10.31.0.221;
    };
};


/* 
zone "0.31.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "zone/2/db.0.31.10.in-addr.arpa";

    allow-query {
        any;
    };
};
*/
```

The first server BIND is listening on `10.31.0.220` and `10.31.0.221`

- `lab.` zone is allowed over `10.31.0.220`
- `demo.lab.` zone is allowed over `10.31.0.221`

using for each zone `allow-query-on`

With `allow-query-on` I always have a denied query when I try to query `demo.lab.` over the parent zone using `10.31.0.220`. Same effect if I query `lab.` over `.221`

```
08-Apr-2020 11:13:19.869 queries: info: client @0x1cf6450 10.31.0.254#50248 (demo.lab): query: demo.lab IN A +E(0)K (10.31.0.220)
08-Apr-2020 11:13:19.869 security: info: client @0x1cf6450 10.31.0.254#50248 (demo.lab): query-on denied
08-Apr-2020 11:13:19.869 query-errors: info: client @0x1cf6450 10.31.0.254#50248 (demo.lab): query failed (REFUSED) for demo.lab/IN/A at query.c:5382
```

It seems that it is not recursing from parent `.220` to child `.221`.
I don't know If I have properly set up the delegation between parent/child. I have read many tutorials some of them are contradictory and made many test but all failed.

Without `allow-query-on` I have an answer on every listening for each domain.

Even with `allow-recursion { any; }` and `allow-recursion-on { any;  };` this does not work.

I don't know if a view is required.

To be honest I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

It is working with 2 view.

```
view "lab" IN {
    match-clients { any; };
    match-destinations { 10.31.0.220; };
    match-recursive-only no;
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-recursion-on { 10.31.0.220; };
    allow-query {
                10.31.0/24;
                10.31.10/24;
                10.31.0.221;
        10.31.0.221;
        };
    allow-query-on {
        10.31.0.220;
        };


    // zone lab.
    zone "lab." IN {
            type master;
            file "zone/2/db-lab";
        allow-query-on { 10.31.0.220; };
    };
    // zone 0.31.10.in-addr.arpa
    zone "0.31.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
                type master;
                file "zone/2/db-0.31.10.in-addr.arpa";
    };

    //notify no;
};


view "demo.lab" IN {
        match-clients { any; };     // source
        match-destinations { 10.31.0.221; };    // destination
        match-recursive-only no;
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-recursion-on { 10.31.0.221; };
    allow-query {
                10.31.0/24;
                10.31.10/24;
                //10.31.0.221;
        };
    allow-query-on {
                10.31.0.221;
        };

    // try demo.lab to lab
    //forward only;
    //forwarders { 10.31.0.220; };

    // zone demo.lab.
        zone "demo.lab." IN {
                type master;
                file "zone/2/db-demo.lab";
        };
/*  
    // zone lab.
    // forward cause dnssec error need to add in global options
    //  dnssec-enable no;
    //  dnssec-validation no;
    zone "lab." IN {
        type forward;
        forwarders { 10.31.0.220; };
    };
*/

    // replace forward
    zone "lab." IN {
        type stub;
        file "zone/2/db-lab";
        masters { 10.31.0.220; };
    };

    // zone 0.31.10.in-addr.arpa
    zone "0.31.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "zone/2/db-0.31.10.in-addr.arpa";
    };

    //notify no;

};
```

Maybe not the best for the first time but no errors in logs.

I needed to remove `ns0.lab.` as NS from `demo.lab.` zone because I had this message in logs and I don't know if it's good or not.

```
notify: notice: client @0x67b450 10.31.0.254#41543: view lab: received notify for zone 'demo.lab': not authoritative
```

Kind Regards